# Change text display in Kendo UI datePicker

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, kendo-ui, datepicker

I've got a kendo datePicker and I'm trying to change the format of the date that appears. Instead of a standard mm/dd/yyyy format, though, I'm trying to make a call to a method that returns a string. I've tried just putting a call to the method under format and text, but it just goes to the default date format. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is the format dynamic or something? There are many possible formats you can provide to the format property, not just mm/dd/yyyy. Why do you need to call a method?

Comment: The format needs to read "X days from now," so the method subtracts the current date from the selected date and returns the proper string. If it's only a difference of one day, it returns "Tomorrow" instead.

Comment: It appears that datepickers are limited to displaying strings that can be formatted using kendo.toString(). Things like "Tomorrow" can't be displayed in the input as far as I know. Why not have it display that in a span next to the datepicker input and bind it to the change event of the datepicker?

Comment: I've been asking around with friends, and it looks like that's what I'll have to do. I actually think it's a better idea than replacing the static date in the datePicker. Thanks.